# AssertionError: You tried to initiate a model of type 'encoder-decoder' with a pretrained model of type 'encoder_decoder'

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

I get this error message:

> AssertionError: You tried to initiate a model of type 'encoder-decoder' with a pretrained model of type 'encoder_decoder'

when I try to run the following code:

```py
from transformers import LongformerTokenizer, EncoderDecoderModel

model = EncoderDecoderModel.from_pretrained("patrickvonplaten/longformer2roberta-cnn_dailymail-fp16")
tokenizer = LongformerTokenizer.from_pretrained("allenai/longformer-base-4096") 

article = """(CNN)James Holmes made his introduction to the world in a Colorado cinema filled with spectators watching a midnight showing of the new Batman movie, The matter will be settled by the jury. CNN\'s Ana Cabrera and Sara Weisfeldt contributed to this report from Denver."""

input_ids = tokenizer(article, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
output_ids = model.generate(input_ids)

print(tokenizer.decode(output_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True))
```

Comment: Which version of transformers are you using?